# How can I set Raspberry Pi Pico as a readable hid device?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, hid, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to send a request from my PC to Pico using libhidapi and return the value I set in Pico. For example, I want to write and then read the address 0x00b0 from the PC using Hidapi. But I get an error in the write function.

I defined Pico as a hid device. But I could not reduce it to callback functions. I write in C in Pico. but it does not come to the tud_hid_get_report_cb function.
Below I shared the code I sent from my computer and the usb descriptor.c in Pico.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "time"

        "github.com/sstallion/go-hid"
)

func main() {
        if err := hid.Init(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        d, err := hid.OpenFirst(0x1038, 0x220e)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        var b [2]byte
        var readBytes [6]byte

        b[0] = 0x0
        b[1] = 0xb0
        n, err := d.Write(b[:])
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Write byte =", n)

        n, err = d.ReadWithTimeout(readBytes[:], time.Millisecond*10)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Read byte =", n)

        fmt.Printf("Read Bytes = %02X\n", readBytes)

        hid.Exit()

}
```

```
#include "tusb.h"
#include "usb_descriptors.h"

#define _PID_MAP(itf, n) ((CFG_TUD_##itf) << (n))
#define USB_PID (0x4000 | _PID_MAP(CDC, 0) | _PID_MAP(MSC, 1) | _PID_MAP(HID, 2) | _PID_MAP(MIDI, 3) | _PID_MAP(AUDIO, 4) | _PID_MAP(VENDOR, 5))

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Device Descriptors
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
tusb_desc_device_t const desc_device = {.bLength = sizeof(tusb_desc_device_t),
                                        .bDescriptorType = TUSB_DESC_DEVICE,
                                        .bcdUSB = 0x0200,

                                        .bDeviceClass = TUSB_CLASS_MISC,
                                        .bDeviceSubClass = MISC_SUBCLASS_COMMON,
                                        .bDeviceProtocol = MISC_PROTOCOL_IAD,
                                        .bMaxPacketSize0 = CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE,

                                        .idVendor = 0x1038,
                                        .idProduct = 0x220e,
                                        .bcdDevice = 0x0100,

                                        .iManufacturer = 0x01,
                                        .iProduct = 0x02,
                                        .iSerialNumber = 0x03,

                                        .bNumConfigurations = 0x01};

uint8_t const* tud_descriptor_device_cb(void) { return (uint8_t const*)&desc_device; }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// HID Report Descriptor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+

enum { REPORT_ID_CONSUMER_CONTROL = 1, REPORT_ID_COUNT };

uint8_t const desc_hid_report[] = {TUD_HID_REPORT_DESC_CONSUMER(HID_REPORT_ID(REPORT_ID_CONSUMER_CONTROL))};

uint8_t const* tud_hid_descriptor_report_cb(uint8_t instance) {
        (void)instance;
        return desc_hid_report;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Configuration Descriptor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
enum { ITF_NUM_AUDIO_CONTROL = 0, ITF_NUM_AUDIO_STREAMING_SPK, ITF_NUM_AUDIO_STREAMING_MIC, ITF_NUM_HID1, ITF_NUM_TOTAL };
#define CONFIG_TOTAL_LEN (TUD_CONFIG_DESC_LEN + CFG_TUD_AUDIO * TUD_AUDIO_HEADSET_STEREO_DESC_LEN + TUD_HID_DESC_LEN)

#define EPNUM_AUDIO_IN 0x01
#define EPNUM_AUDIO_OUT 0x01

#define EPNUM_HID1 0x86

uint8_t const desc_configuration[] = {
        TUD_CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR(1, ITF_NUM_TOTAL, 0, CONFIG_TOTAL_LEN, 0x00, 100),

        TUD_AUDIO_HEADSET_STEREO_DESCRIPTOR(2, EPNUM_AUDIO_OUT, EPNUM_AUDIO_IN | 0x80),

        TUD_HID_DESCRIPTOR(ITF_NUM_HID1, 0, HID_ITF_PROTOCOL_NONE, sizeof(desc_hid_report), EPNUM_HID1, CFG_TUD_HID_EP_BUFSIZE, 10),
};

uint8_t const* tud_descriptor_configuration_cb(uint8_t index) {
        (void)index;  // for multiple configurations
        return desc_configuration;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// String Descriptors
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+

// array of pointer to string descriptors
char const* string_desc_arr[] = {
        (const char[]){0x09, 0x04},     // 0: is supported language is English (0x0409)
        "TinyUSB",                      // 1: Manufacturer
        "TinyUSB headset",              // 2: Product
        "000001",                       // 3: Serials, should use chip ID
        "TinyUSB Speakers",             // 4: Audio Interface
        "TinyUSB Microphone",           // 5: Audio Interface
};

static uint16_t _desc_str[32];

uint16_t const* tud_descriptor_string_cb(uint8_t index, uint16_t langid) {
        (void)langid;

        uint8_t chr_count;

        if (index == 0) {
                memcpy(&_desc_str[1], string_desc_arr[0], 2);
                chr_count = 1;
        } else {
                // Convert ASCII string into UTF-16

                if (!(index < sizeof(string_desc_arr) / sizeof(string_desc_arr[0]))) return NULL;

                const char* str = string_desc_arr[index];

                // Cap at max char
                chr_count = (uint8_t)strlen(str);
                if (chr_count > 31) chr_count = 31;

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < chr_count; i++) {
                        _desc_str[1 + i] = str[i];
                }
        }

        _desc_str[0] = (uint16_t)((TUSB_DESC_STRING << 8) | (2 * chr_count + 2));

        return _desc_str;
}
```